# errors with charAt method in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, charat

I'm working on a small project with javascript. I am using charAt method to get the first character in a line from ace editor.
here's my code:

```
function checkFirstChar (lineNo) {
  var words = lines[lineNo].split(" ");
  var firstChar = words[0].charAt(0);

  if (firstChar == "." || firstChar == "#") {
    return 0;
  }
  else return 1;
}
```

Where lines is an array or strings, which is extracted from the ace editor. Problem is, this works fine when the first character is '#'. But when the first character is '.', it doesn't take it as a dot '.' Instead, it takes it as a "" (empty string). Can anyone help me out here ? Whats wrong with it ?

Edit:
This is how I took the array, lines.

```
for(var i = 0, lines = new Array(numOfLines); i<numOfLines; i++ ){
        lines[i] = editor.session.getLine(i);
}
```

Most confusing part is, when I make an alert from words[0], it shows the word with the dot "."

Comment: show `lines` and your invocation of the function `checkFirstChar`. It should work fine if the code is as is

Comment: `words` begins with a space?

Comment: @AmitJoki I've added some additional info. Thanx for the help.

Comment: @ThisaruGuruge try to replicate your problem in jsfiddle. There is nothing wrong with your code, as far as I can see

Comment: Sounds like you've got some invisible zero-width character before you dot. Try to log the `words[0].charCodeAt(0)`

Comment: ah I've found out the problem. There were tabs, and seems like {charAt()} reads them also. I used {var firstChar = words[0].trim.charAt(0);} instead {var firstChar = words[0].charAt(0);} Thanx everyone for the help :) –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the code. It works perfectly fine for me. Please check the values that are being inserted in your array. I suppose it should work fine.
I implemented the following code:

```
function myFunc() {
  var words = ".sdf dfsf #sdsd df";
  var firstChar = words[0].charAt(0);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "";
  if (firstChar == "." || firstChar == "#")
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "bingo";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using charAt(), you should use your string as a table of chars.

```
 var firstChar = words[0].charAt(0);
```

can be replaced by

```
 var firstChar = words[0][0];
```

Comment: What could be wrong with `charAt()`? Also, oldIE does not support indexed access of characters on strings.